# Creating windows 8 bootable usb stick under linux with Winusb (saucy) changes my iso file hashes - is it normal, bug or harmfull behavior?

Tags: iso, malware

There is a lot of questions about creation of windows 8 usb stick in linux environment. And a lot of answers pointing to Winusb(saucy) as an app that can do it. I installed it too, using this method:

- downloading 64bit

  ```
  wget https://launchpad.net/~colingille/+archive/freshlight/+files/winusb_1.0.11+saucy1_amd64.deb
  ```
- Install Winusb

  ```
  sudo dpkg -i winusb_1.0.11+saucy1*
  ```
- Fix dependencies errors

  ```
  sudo apt-get -f install
  ```

I check my iso file md5 and sha1 hashes and they are Ok. Then I start Winusb and create bootable usb from iso file. After it finished working iso file hashes are not the same any more. The size of the iso file is the same.

So my question is is it some harmfull virus-like behavior, or is it some bug or is it normal at all? Does anyone experience such problem with winusb or is it my system? How can I
find what changes?

I took new iso an restored old one - to compare. Used `diff -r -q [iso1] [iso2]` command - result was - files differ.

I extracted them into the different folders to find exactly where they differ and used "diff -r -q [dir1] [dir2]" command - result was empty. Like if they where identical.

So again: Is it ok that iso-file hashes are changing? And how can I find what data in iso is changing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's normal. Winusb adds some data to iso before writing it to USB .
Don't worry. You should be able to install windows from USB device written by winusb.